# Hql constructor query with null parameter in object

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am trying to join 2 tables and add the result to a new object via a constructor query. Not all ids from the left table are in the right table. Thus via an outer join I expect to get all the results from the left table with results from the right table, and if there are no results a null value.

It looks like the object can not hold null values. When I tried below code I only got 4 results, all of them have a corresponding value in the other table. When I remove argument 2 from the x.x.x.PersonWithPartner object then all 49 (expected) results are shown (I only modified second argument, query is the same)

Is my conclusion correct that null values cannot be passed to a query constructor? I have tried to put null as second argument hardcoded but then I got an error message, which also made me think that null values cannot be passed as argument.

How could I resolve this issue, is it possible to make the second argument optional? Because argument two is an object this would automatically resolve to a null value, solving my problem.

I recreated my query in pgadmin and got the result I expected. By removing the LEFT OUTER JOIN (and the second argument from object) the query returns all the records I am expecting.

The stripped down query

```
SELECT new  x.x.x.PersonWithPartner(p, relation.related)
FROM Person p
LEFT OUTER JOIN p.relation relation
```

x.x.x.PersonWithPartner object

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class PersonWithPartner {
    private Person person;
    private Person partner;

    public NatuurlijkPersoonWithPartner(Person person, Person partner) {
        this.person = person;
        this.partner = partner;
    }
```

I expect per record an object with the first argument always filled and the second argument either an object found by the join or null.

Comment: Is there a link table between person and related? Is related another person? Did you take a look at the generated SQL query?

Comment: Yes there are OneToMany and ManyToOne relation between the objects. No not yet. I haven't been able to get that working yet. I'll try that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT new  x.x.x.PersonWithPartner(p, related)
FROM Person p
LEFT OUTER JOIN p.relation relation
LEFT OUTER JOIN relation.related related
```

I don't know if that works. But probably `relation.related` created an implicit inner join.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem. I now get all records from left table with null or value from the right one.